# Как установить 3D pdf на сайт?

Tags: html, веб-программирование, pdf, 3d

Подскажите, как установить 3D pdf модель на сайт? Выглядит примерно так: 3D модель можно двигать курсором в разных направлениях. Сколько искал в инете ничего не нашел, кроме как утилит, которые превращают pdf в 3D файлы, но это не то. 
Есть необходимость, чтоб на странице сайта, можно было выбрать модель и покрутить ее, рассмотреть со всех сторон.) Возможно кто сталкивался с подобным? Или может что посоветуете по делу?

Comment: Возможно подойдёт: `kolor panotour`

Answer (score -1):

Нашёл сайт - скетчфаб. С помощью инспектора кода, можно посмотреть исходный код страницы. Код с одной из моделей:

```
<canvas class="canvas" data-modelUid="ad592b72ff844162bfea8ca103162854" data-action="create-hotspot">
</canvas>
<div class="loading-container">
    <div class="secondary-progress">
        <div class="secondary-progress-percentage"></div>
        <div class="secondary-progress-display"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="main-progress">
        <img alt="Loading 3D Model" src="https://media.sketchfab.com/models/ad592b72ff844162bfea8ca103162854/thumbnails/8bdc48eebcc84c1f85ced62c04407216/8b832d82919e4038b70de88a7529fc6f.jpeg" class="loading-thumbnail" />
        <div class="main-progress-wrapper">
            <div class="main-progress-percentage loading-percentage">0%</div>
            <p>Loading 3D model</p>
            <div class="main-progress-display">
                <div class="main-progress-display__progress"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```